# What's the verb form when use "I am" with "Who" restrictive clause?

Tags: present-tense

In grammaly software, When  I wrote "I am" with Restrictive clause  "who" , for a  simple present sentence,
with verb in it's  base form, it suggests to change  the verb to singular form.

I'm a  person who **take** notes.

I'm a  person who **takes** notes.

Could someone  please confirm that  is the "take" is the correct verb form for "I am" when it used with who?

Comment: Delete "I'm a" and what do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to say "takes", you can't say "take".

The sentence has to be:

> I'm a person who takes notes.

If you are **the** one who is meant to take notes, you should say:

> I'm the person who takes notes.

Let's change the "takes notes" to something like "does stuff".

If you say:

> I'm a person who does stuff.

It would sound good.

But if you say:

> I'm a person who do stuff.

That wouldn't be a proper sentence, but you probably can understand that this is the same logic as the "take"/"takes" example.

Comment: Thank you . U11-Forward.

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva Your welcome :-)